# html email template pushes array down

Tags: html, css, email

I am making a email template and inserting an python list with a forloop, the problem I am having is that now since I already designed the template with a  I cant get right array to align perfectly with the left array and the right array is pushed down.

[Showing the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWYUq.png)
The right array is pushed down.

I need to get the array fixed but not sure how to do it since if I change the template design it starts effecting the email.

```
<tr>
          <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" valign="top" style=
          "padding: 10px;">
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding=
            "0" border="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                <td width="50%" class="stack-column-center" align=
                "center">
                  <table role="presentation section" class=
                  "presentation-section" cellspacing="0"
                  cellpadding="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                      <th style="text-align: center">
                        <h3 style=
                        " font-size:14px; font-weight:800; margin:0 0 10px; font-family:Helvetica;">
                        Tele companies
                        </h3>
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                      {% for comp, values in vis_domain.companies %}
                    <tr>
                      <td style="text-align: center">
                        <p style=
                        "margin:5px 0; font-size:14px; font-family:Helvetica;">
                        <span style="font-size:13px ;color:gray; ">{{ values.0 }}</span> {{ comp }}
                        </p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                      {% endfor %}

                  </table>
                </td><!-- Column : END -->
                <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                <td width="50%" class="stack-column-center" align=
                "center">
                  <table role="presentation" class=
                  "presentation-section" cellspacing="0"
                  cellpadding="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                      <th style="text-align: center">
                        <h3 style=
                        " font-size:14px; font-weight:800; margin:0 0 10px; font-family:Helvetica;">
                        Tags used in chats
                        </h3>
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                      {% for tags in vis_domain.tags %}
                    <tr>
                      <td style="text-align: center">
                        <p style="margin:5px 0; font-size:14px;font-family:Helvetica;">
                        <span style="font-size:13px ;color:gray;">{{ tags.tag_count }}</span> {{ tags.name }}
                        </p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                      {% endfor %}

                  </table>
                </td><!-- Column : END -->
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr><!-- 2 Even Columns : END -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a style to the td's and specify the vertical alignment.
Try editing the first `td` after the 2 `<!-- Column : BEGIN -->` comments like this:

```
<td width="50%" class="stack-column-center" align="center" style="vertical-align: top;">
```

Comment: Glad it worked! For reference, I've checked [vertical-align](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/vertical-align/) here to know if the property was supported by major email clients :)